# Is this property regarding infinite sets true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let, $\{A_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Is is true that:
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(S - A_n) = S - \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n?$$

Thanks.

Comment: $S=\{1\}$, $A_1=\{1\}$, $A_n=\emptyset$ for $n\ge2$.

Comment: Parentheses are important. Do you mean $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(S-A_n)?$$

Comment: @bof, yes that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S=\mathbb{N}$ and $A_n=\{n\}$. So $$\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(S-A_n)=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\mathbb{N}-\{n\})=\mathbb{N}\neq\emptyset=\mathbb{N}-\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{n\}$$
Hence, this is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

As bof points out, if you mean $S-A=\{s-a:s\in S, a\in A\}$, then it's true that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(S-A_n)\subset \bigcup_{n=1}(S-A_n)$. Since $a \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(S-A_n) \implies a\in S - A_n\text{(for some n)}\implies a=s-a_n\in \bigcup_{n=1}(S-A_n)$. The same for the converse.

Answer (score 0):

The left side means that There is an element of S that is not in some $A_n$. The right hand side means there is an element of S that is not in any $A_n$. So the left set contains the right set, but not vice versa. If we have a an element in all $A_n$ but one, it won't be in on the right.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. You are assuming that $S-A$ means $S\setminus A$ but it could just as well mean $\{s-a:s\in S,\ a\in A\}$.